# Draggable object collision

Tags: box2d, coronasdk, draggable

So I have a dynamic draggable object that I want it to collide with a static wall. I managed to get it done by adding a boolean that becomes false in the collision function, and back on again in touch began and it works perfect, except for one thing, when I drag the object very fast it still goes through the wall. I even added this line of code:

```
physics.setContinuous( false )
```

But it didn't make any difference. So, my question is, how to get the physics engine to detect a collision when one of the objects is moving fast?

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround/solution for your problem

- The best solution is to make the "walls" thicker, if that is possible within your game,
- You may increase the [velocity](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/setVelocityIterations.html) and [position](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/setPositionIterations.html) iterations

  ```
  physics.setVelocityIterations(value) (8 is default value) 

  physics.setPositionIterations(value) (3 is default value)
  ```
- use `object.isBullet = true` more  [information](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/isBullet.html)

Last two sugesstions may result in a slight performance penalty.

More information you can find from links below

- [how-do-i-stop-a-draggable-physic-object-from-going-through-a-wall](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/57654-how-do-i-stop-a-draggable-physic-object-from-going-through-a-wall/)
- [physics-object-passing-through-wall-object-in-corona-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229076/physics-object-passing-through-wall-object-in-corona-sdk)
- [drag-physic-object-in-corona-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716394/drag-physic-object-in-corona-sdk)
- [How to Drag Objects](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/24/tutorial-how-to-drag-objects/)

Comment: You don't seem to have read the question, I already solved the problem of getting the wall to block the draggable object, the problem now is it doesn't happen when the object is being dragged too fast.

Comment: You don't seem to have check/read all links from my list. So I edit my answer and put some suggestions from second link to you in my answer. Hope this help.

Comment: I already tried these stuff before, the 2 lines of codes above doesn't do much, and I can't make the walls bigger than what they already are(20px)